# Best method to use for Multicasting voice over local network with over 100 phones

Tags: android, udp, wifip2p

like the title says im intending to make a VOIP like application that can  connect over 100 phones without internet , allowing them to talk to each other just like walkie talkie.

now for connection itself there are 2 ways either Tethering or Wifi direct (P2P) , and there are also some ways for sending and receiving including UDP or TCP. if i want to use UDP , i guess best way is Tethering but the question is , is udp reliable in voip and will its data be received sequencely? or how can clients identify which packets belong to them (in case some other groups are in range and using same protocol)? also since P2P offers grouping , here comes the question how many clients can direct Wifi grouping handle effectively .

also if there is any better way , any idea will be welcomed . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition UDP isn't reliable (it's send and forget, there's no "built-in" acknowledgement or retry) and there's no guarantee that packets will be received sequentially. You can use simple measures like Jitter Buffers and packet-sequencing to solve this, though.

Depending on other factors, it might not be the end of the world if you occasionally drop packets, especially if you're using a Jitter Buffer and have designed your software with that in mind.

You might also be interested in RTP:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol

Comment: would you suggest the RTP protocol ? i guess its based on udp right ? can it handle such amount of users?

Comment: Yes, my understanding is that that's generally how it's implemented.